# Sentence Embeddings with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, python-multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers

I would like to compute sentence embeddings on a very large text dataset in the fastest way possible. For this purpose I have access to a multi-core CPU (x32).

My current code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModel 

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english')
model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english')

input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer(sentences)['input_ids'])[None, :][0] # sentences is a list() 
sentence_embeddings = [model(input_id).last_hidden_state[0][0].numpy() for input_id in input_ids]
```

Kindly advise how I may be able to speed up this block using parallelism. I have tried various solutions on multiprocessing available on the web, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.